# android Try to open keyboard after click on editText

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to open keyboard and i get in the logcat

> 682-682/com.android.inputmethod.latin V/InputMethodService﹕
>   onEvaluateInputViewShown: config.hardKeyboardHidden = 1

my code:

```
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Declare this at top of your activity

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

and inside edittext just use this,

```
imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
```

or else you can try this too,

```
InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  if(m != null){
      m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```